# the collision function is not working properly

Tags: python, pygame

There is a "player" (sprite) and a group of walls (other_group), also sprites. When creating a wall with NOT the same x/y coordinates, the sprite.spritecollide method does not work correctly. Horizontally everything is ok, vertically the player just falls into the wall.
[fullcode](https://github.com/ariewhite/Socoban/blob/master/Socoban.py)

```
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(other_group)
        self.image = wall_images
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(x, y)

# player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, speed, x, y):
        super().__init__(player_group)
        self.speed = speed
        self.frames = []
        self.cur_frame = 0
        self.image = animation_down[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(x, y)
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def possibility_of_movement(self, directory_of_movement):
        if directory_of_movement == 'right':
            tester = Player(self.speed, self.rect.x + self.speed, self.rect.y)
        elif directory_of_movement == 'left':
            tester = Player(self.speed, self.rect.x - self.speed, self.rect.y)
        elif directory_of_movement == 'up':
            tester = Player(self.speed, self.rect.y - self.speed, self.rect.x)
        else:
            tester = Player(self.speed, self.rect.y + self.speed, self.rect.x)

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(tester, other_group, dokill=False, collided=pygame.sprite.collide_rect_ratio(0.7)):
            tester.kill()
            return False
        else:
            return True

tile2 = Tile(264, 264)
tile3 = Tile(264+64, 264)
tile4 = Tile(446, 446)
tile4 = Tile(382, 382)

while running:

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and pos_x > 5 and player.possibility_of_movement('left'):
        pos_x -= player.speed
        left = True
        right = False
        down = False
        up = False
```

Comment: more readable is `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` instead of `self.rect[0]` and `self.rect[1]`

Comment: you set values in wrong order when you create Player for tests. - in `up` and `down` you set `y+speed, x` but you should do `x, y+speed`

Comment: @furas
thank you for ur help! 
Everything is working well now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it but I think all problem is because you set values in wrong order when you create `tester` - and it checks collision with wrong place (with place which doesn't have any wall) and it doesn't stop.

For `up` (and similar for `down`) you set `y-speed,x` but you have to set `x, y-speed`

Correct oder of values in `Player()`

```
elif directory_of_movement == 'up':
    tester = Player(self.speed, self.rect.x, self.rect.y - self.speed)
else:
    tester = Player(self.speed, self.rect.x, self.rect.y + self.speed)
```